# Find a set of vectors {u, v} in $R^4$ that spans the solution set of the equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a set of vectors {u, v} in $\mathbb R^4$ that spans the solution set of the equations
>
> $x - y + 2z +3w = 0$
>
> $4x + 2y - z + 3w = 0$
>
> $ u =\begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}, v =\begin{bmatrix}\\\\\\\end{bmatrix}$

How exactly can I do that, what do they mean by "that *spans*"

Comment: They mean "solve $\pmatrix{1 & -1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & -1 & 3}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z \\ w} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$".  Do it exactly the same way as you were doing it before.  It's just that this time you know that there'll be two free variables because you'll end up with $\mathbf x = r\pmatrix{\\ \\ \\} + s\pmatrix{\\ \\ \\}$.

Comment: I got RREF $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1/2&3/2\\0&1&-3/2&-3/2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Bye_World the two free variables are obviously $z$ and $w$ right?

Comment: I am so confused. I got $x = \frac{-1}{2} z - \frac{3}{2} w$ and $y = 3/2 + 3/2 = 3$

Comment: I posted an answer.  See if you understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, to solve this you do exactly what you've been doing in all of your other problems.  Since you weren't sure of your answer, I went ahead and worked it out for you.

The augmented matrix equation that you're trying to solve is this one:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & -1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 4 & 2 & -1 & 3 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

Now I'll do Gaussian elimination to solve it.  Note that I'm going to leave off the final column of $0$'s because no elementary row operation will actually change them.  So just imagine that column still being there:

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & -1 & 3\end{bmatrix} &\sim_{R_2 \to R_2-4R_1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 6 & -9 & -9\end{bmatrix} \\ &\sim_{R_2\to \frac 16R_2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac 32 & -\frac 32\end{bmatrix} \\ &\sim_{R_1\to R_1+R_2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac 12 & \frac 32 \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac 32 & -\frac 32\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

This is the RREF of your matrix.  Now we see that columns $3$ and $4$ don't have pivots so we set $z=s$, $s\in \Bbb R$ and $w=t$, $t\in \Bbb R$.  Then we write down the equations that the above matrix represents and substitute these new variables:

$$\begin{cases} x +\frac 12z+\frac 32w=0 \\ y-\frac 32z-\frac 32w=0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} x= -\frac 12s-\frac 32t \\ y=\frac 32s+\frac 32 t\end{cases}$$

So each element of the solution set is of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac 12s-\frac 32t \\ \frac 32s+\frac 32 t \\ s \\ t\end{bmatrix} = s\begin{bmatrix} -\frac 12 \\ \frac 32 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} -\frac 32 \\ \frac 32 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix},\quad s,t\in\Bbb R$$

Thus the set $\{(-\frac 12, \frac 32, 1, 0),(-\frac 32,\frac 32, 0, 1)\}$ spans the space.  But fractions are a little annoying.  So what we can do is multiply each vector by $2$.  Really what we're doing here is defining new variables $s'=\frac 12s$ and $t'=\frac 12t$. Then plugging these into the above and moving the constant inside the vectors we get $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\{(-1,3,2,0),(-3,3,0,2)\}}$$

Note that these vectors are not unique.  There are an infinite number of other pairs of vectors which will span this space.  For instance, Vineet's solution is another perfectly valid pair.

---

Now that we see this exercise just asked to you solve it the same way as all the others you've done so far, I'll tackle your question about what the word *span* means.  Let $S=\{\mathbf u_1, \dots, \mathbf u_k\}\subset \Bbb R^n$.

**Definition:** A *linear combination* of $S$ is a vector $\mathbf w$ such that $$\mathbf w = w_1\mathbf u_1 + \cdots + w_k\mathbf u_k$$ for some $w_1, \dots, w_k \in \Bbb R$.

Example:  The vector $(-7,-2,3)$ is a linear combination of $\{(1,2,3),(3,2,1)\}$ because $$(-7,-2,3) = 2(1,2,3)-3(3,2,1)$$

However $(1,0,0)$ is **not** a linear combination of $\{(1,2,3),(3,2,1)\}$ because there are no numbers $a,b$ such that $$(1,0,0) = a(1,2,3)+b(3,2,1)$$

**Definition:** The *span* of $S$ is the set of **all** linear combinations of $S$.  I.e. $$\operatorname{span}(S) = \{\mathbf w \in \Bbb R^n \mid\mathbf w = w_1\mathbf u_1 + \cdots + w_k\mathbf u_k\}$$

Examples:
$$\begin{align}(1)\quad &\operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\} = \operatorname{span}\{(10,9,0),(e,-\pi,0)\} = \text{the $xy$-plane} \\ (2)\quad &\operatorname{span}\{(1,2,3)\} = \text{the line containing $O$ parallel to $(1,2,3)$}\end{align}$$

**Lemma:** The span of any set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. (*Note: I'm not going to prove this lemma here, it's just important to know.*)

So this question is asking you to find a set of two vectors whose span is the solution set to your system of linear equations.

Comment: Thank you for the **excellent** explanation. Wow.

Comment: Studying for a exam, and was curious; Do we know that our two set of vectors will be $4\times1$ because we have **4 free variables** ? Similarly do we know we will have **2 sets of vectors** because we have **2 pivot columns?**

Comment: @Yusha Not all of the variables are free.  But you know that the solution set will consist of vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ (AKA $4\times 1$ matrices) because there are $4$ variables in total (each row will represent one variable).  You will know that the basis will contain $2$ vectors because there are $2$ pivots (just a note on the terminology: the pivots are the $1$ entries themselves, not the whole columns).

Comment: So basically we know that there will be $4$ rows based on the number of **columns** since each column has a variable associated with it right? i.e $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$

Comment: @Yusha That's right.$ $

Comment: Last question, sorry to bother you again. But suppose I have 1 pivot. Does that imply that I will always have two sets? I'm finding a matrix currently where I have 1 pivot. So does that mean I will have at least two sets? I'm currently doing a problem where I am finding a **Basis** for a NullSpaceA or is this only particular to finding basis for NulA?

Comment: @Yusha You seem to be using the word "set" incorrectly so I don't exactly know what you mean.  The number of vectors in the basis for the solution space of a type $Ax=b$ equation will be equal to the number of free variables (i.e. $\text{number of columns of } A - \text{ number of pivots}$).  The nullspace of a matrix $A$ is just the solution space of $Ax=0$, so you use the same method but it's even easier because you don't really need to keep track of the column of $0$'s of your augmented matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the free variables. To get the $u$, put $x=0,y=1$ and for $v$, put $x=1,y=0$ and solve two equations in $z$ and $w$. Finally you will get

$u=[0,3,3,-1]^T$ & $v=[1,0,1,-1]^T$

Please note the magnitude of these vectors are irrelevant. So you can multiply it with any scaler you want. In case of $u$, I multiplied vectore with $3$.

Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: This is the only correct answer. I am trying to work through how you got this. What does $^T$ supposed to mean? We haven' t done anything that looks like that

Comment: Also why are $x$ and $y$ the free variables? I put it in **RREF** form and they are clearly **Basic Variables** I thought free variables would be $z$ and $w$ ??

Comment: Also what are you talking about "put $x = 0$".. what? Can you show your work?

Comment: $^T$ means transpose. And you have 2 equations and 4 variables, so clearly there must be two variables. So you can choose any of the two variables as free variables. And to find the basis vectors, just put the one FV (free variable) = 1 and other FV = 0. So by doing this, you will get two equations in other dependent variables. Solve these equations and you will get the vector. For other vector, follow same procedure and this is the general method to find the span.

Answer (score 1):

what means:  the set of solutions $(x, y, z, w)$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$, of an
equation of type $ax + by + cz + dw = 0$ , $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{R}$, is the sub space kernel in $\Bbb{R}^4$
of the linear form $(x, y, z, w)\rightarrow a x + by + cz + dw$ ,
so this kernel is by rank theorem  (case not a, b, c, d, all zero)
a hyperplane of $\Bbb{R}^4$,  so a  sub space  of dimension  $3$.

The solution set $(x, y, z, w)$ of $n$ equations of the same type
as above, is the subspace obtained by the intersection of the
solutions set of each equation.

in your case $n=2$,
the question suppose that this intersection of solution  can it be
generated by two vectors $u$ and $v$, that is all solutions are in
the form $a u+b v$ where $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$