# What is an example of a matrix A such that its image is spanned by the vector (1,5)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't quite understand what a span exactly is. But based on my understanding, it's basically the same as linear combination. Does the question also mean that im(A) is a linear combination of (1,5)

Comment: Look at the bottom of Bye_World's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838820/find-a-set-of-vectors-u-v-in-r4-that-spans-the-solution-set-of-the-equatio/1839173).  He (/she?) goes over what span is and gives a couple of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
5 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Or, more generally, take $A$ to have $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$ as a column and zeros for the remaining columns. In particular, $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$ works. The span of $A$ is the collection of all products of the form $Ab$ for some compatible column vector $b$ (i.e. $b$ has as many elements as $A$ has columns).

Comment: Can you give me an example of span? I still. don't get it, thanks